# Correct way to copy-paste file location from nautilus into a file chooser?

Tags: shortcut-keys, nautilus, 20.04

To paste a file or directory into the file-chooser dialogue of any application, I used to be able to select and copy the file from any Nautilus window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>, then paste the whole pathname into the file-name field of the chooser with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>, whatever directory it was currently showing.

Since Ubuntu 19.04 (Nautilus 3.30), when you copy a file in Nautilus the clipboard includes a two-line media-type and action before the path, as follows:

```
x-special/nautilus-clipboard
copy
file:///path/name
```

So, when you paste into the file-name field of a chooser dialogue, it no longer works - you get just the first line `x-special/nautilus-clipboard` not the pathname.

Is there a correct way to paste these new 3-line Nautilus path-names into the file-name field of a file-chooser?

---

I've discovered a work-round where I can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd> in Nautilus and copy the path of the containing directory, then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd> in the file-chooser and paste the containing directory with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>. This at least gets the chooser to the right location in the file system, but you still have to select the file you want. So this feels more like a walk-round the houses than a work-round!

From reading the developer's discussions, inclusion of this metadata in the clipboard seems to be part of some master-plan. For instance, once I had copied one of these 3-line Nautilus path names to my clipboard, I noticed that right clicking on a gnome-terminal shows a new entry `Paste as filenames`, which pastes the filename(s) surrounded by quotes {see Note 1}.

So, is the master-plan that a matching paste action will eventually be written for the file-chooser that recognizes this new 3-line clipboard entry? But in the meantime we're left with a temporary regression? Or perhaps there is some new way that I'm meant to be pasting these pathnames - hence my question.

---

{Note 1}: Incidentally, `Paste` is also on the right-click menu of gnome-terminal, which allows you to paste the above three lines into the terminal. Useful eh? I imagine no-one will use that menu more than once! Similarly, Ctrl-Shift-v used to paste the pathname, but now it pastes the above three lines into the terminal.

Comment: This is likely already fixed as I am not seeing the three lines in Ubuntu 22.04. Select the file or folder whose path you’d like to copy in Nautilus. Ctrl+c to copy in Nautilus then Ctrl+Shift+v to paste to terminal.

Comment: It does seem to be fixed for me now too (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS). I guess I leave the question open, with these comments to 'close' it (given it's not a formal bug report).

Answer (score 0):

As of 22.04 it works fine between Nautilus and Terminal.

What still doesn't work (anymore) is to paste it into the file-chooser dialogue of Firefox (at least in v101 in the Snap version).

Comment: Can you give the exact sequence that doesn't work. If I select then copy a filename in nautilus (even in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS), then in FF 101.0.1 (64-bit, but not snap) File > Open File... > CTRL-V, it now correctly writes the filename into the chooser, like it used to before I asked about this 'bug' (which does now appear to be fixed, at least for me).

Comment: I think the issue is solved.

As for 22.04 with snap Firefox 102 in the file-chooser when pressing `Ctrl-l` I don't get the option to 'Enter Location' (paste the path). Same with Chromium 103.

In contrast, with Web 42.1 (Epiphany) the desired `Ctrl-l` &`Ctrl-v` sequence works as expected.